# minizip/unzip.h file not found

Tags: ios, iphone, zip, ssziparchive

I am making an app which zips/unzips files into documents directory using the SSZipArchive from [this following github link](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive). Then I added the following to my Xcode project,

1. Add SSZipArchive.h, SSZipArchive.m, and minizip to your project.
2. Add the libz library to your target

Added the necessary code in my project to zip the file, but I am getting the following lexical or preprocessor issue "minizip/unzip.h file not found". I am using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: You need to provide Search Paths in the configuration, telling Xcode where to search for the headers.

Comment: @DavidH:Can you provide me a more info about what exactly I need to do in Search Paths?

Comment: For the moment put in a fully qualified path in to each folder. Create a demo project with these projects and upload to Dropbox. Or search SO for Xcode and search paths - this has been heavily discussed here.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you forgot to add the minizip folder to the project?

[image]